# Como colocar a constraint zerofill no Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Boa tarde.
Estou tendo um problema para fazer uso da constraint zerofill no Laravel porque
vi que não consta na documentação.

Tenho um campo na minha tabela que é matrícula e na minha view estou limitando, esse campo a 5 dígitos, portanto o valor máximo que ele pode atingir é: 99999. Porém gostaria que quando o usuário digitasse um número de matrícula sem utilizar todos os dígitos, os espaços fosse preenchidos com 0.

Por exemplo, o usuário informa o número de matrícula: 450.
No banco deveria está mostrando 00450.

Como posso fazer isso no Laravel?

Minha migration está assim:

```
$table->integer('matricula')->unique();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o **Mutators** ou **Accessors** para fazer isso. O **Mutatosr** atuaria como um **SET**,  antes de salvar no banco, ele verificaria a quantidade de dígitos e acrescentaria os zeros no inicio. o **Accessors** seria como o **GET**, ao pega o valor do banco, ele verificaria a quantidade de dígitos e adicionaria na frente do valor, mas apenas para questão de visualização.

Você pode ver exemplos no link:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/eloquent-mutators-and-accessors-in-laravel--cms-30312